# API to setup Face unlock (only if feature provided by the Device) for a particular app in versions below 9.0

Tags: android, biometrics

I am trying to support Android OS face unlock only for my particular app if User opts to. As I browse, I could find that there was an API called FingerPrintManager and now a new API called Biometric Prompt (compat). I Thought this Biometric prompt will support all biometric authentication like IRIS, Face, FingerPrint etc. But as I go through the code I can see the only FingerPrint unlock Support. I also read about android FaceDetector which is different implementation altogether.

I tried this BiometricPromptCompat sample as well 
[Sample](https://github.com/natiginfo/biometricprompt-compat-java). But this is only supporting Fingerprint, even at code level!

Do suggest if there is any other Official API or any other way through which,

1. Check on a device whether Face unlock feature is available, enabled/disabled
2. Try to Authenticate and get callback of success/failure.

If there is no such API available at all, then from when Android is officially supporting this feature? I could not find any concrete documentation about this Face Unlock feature official support.

Please suggest.